# MySQL select date range from table where there's only one column for date

Tags: mysql, sql

having this record in MySQL database:

---

```
 emp_name |   team   |  start date   | level |
----------+----------+---------------+--------
john      |  alpha   |  2013-may-28  |   1   |
john      |  beta    |  2013-apr-05  |   3   |
john      |  beta    |  2013-jan-03  |   1   |
john      |  gamma   |  2012-dec-04  |   3   |
john      |  gamma   |  2012-sep-28  |   2   |
john      |  gamma   |  2012-sep-11  |   1   |
john      |  beta    |  2012-jul-17  |   3   |
john      |  beta    |  2012-may-03  |   1   |
john      |  alpha   |  2012-feb-12  |   3   |
john      |  alpha   |  2012-jan-01  |   1   |
```

how should i know that john is a member of team:

```
       | from        | to
 ---------------------------------
 alpha | 2012-jan-01 | 2012-may-03
 beta  | 2012-may-03 | 2012-sep-11
 gamma | 2012-sep-11 | 2013-jan-03
 beta  | 2013-jan-03 | 2013-may-28
 alpha | 2013-may-28 | now
```

i don't know what to put in my WHERE clause to achieve this..i only need to have the team name, the date he started on that team, and the end date on that team..level column in not important..

Comment: Either the end date is not recorded, in which case you are out of luck, or it is assumed that the date prior to the next date in the table is the end date

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'm out of luck this time. i cannot add column to this table. but still hoping that someone out there encountered the same problem from the past and have a solution.

Comment: how do you know end date ?

Comment: if the next record has a new team name, then that record's startdate is the end date of the preceding record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT emp_name, team, min(start_date) start_date, end_date
  FROM (
    SELECT t1.emp_name, t1.team, t1.start_date, min(t2.start_date) end_date
      FROM table1 t1
 LEFT JOIN table1 t2
        ON t1.emp_name = t2.emp_name
       AND t1.team != t2.team
       AND t1.start_date < t2.start_date
  GROUP BY t1.emp_name, t1.team, t1.start_date) t3
GROUP BY emp_name, team, end_date
ORDER BY start_date
```

[Demo: SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32d48/31)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT emp_name,min(startdate) as startdate,max(ldate) as enddate,team
FROM (
  SELECT emp_name,startdate ,team,
  @n:=if(@lastteam=team,@n,@n+1) rank,
  @l:=if(@enddate=startdate,startdate,@enddate) ldate,
  @lastteam:=team, @enddate:=startdate 
    FROM t, (SELECT @n := 0,@lastteam:='',@enddate:='') n
    ORDER BY startdate desc
  ) m
GROUP BY rank
```

SQL FIDDLE here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/860fd/20